# Python how to add two elements of a dataframe keeping the result before

Tags: python, list, loops, dataframe, addition

I would like to add values ​​in my dataframe between them but each time keeping the result of the addition before.

To put it simply, i would like to do :

```
df['col'][0]
df['col'][0] + df['col'][1] 
df['col'][0] + df['col'][1] + df['col'][2]
df['col'][0] + df['col'][1] + df['col'][2] + df['col'][3]
               .
               .
               .
df['col'][0] + ... + df['col'][n]
```

I would like to put each of the values ​​in a list.

Could you help me ?
thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried the `+=` operator?

Comment: This is a *cummulative* sum. You do this with `df['col'].cumsum()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
In [679]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[5, 3, 6, 4],  
     ...:                    "B":[11, 2, 4, 3],  
     ...:                    "C":[4, 3, 8, 5],  
     ...:                    "D":[5, 4, 2, 8]})                                                                                                                                                             

In [680]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[680]: 
   A   B  C  D
0  5  11  4  5
1  3   2  3  4
2  6   4  8  2
3  4   3  5  8

In [682]: df.A.cumsum(axis=0)                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[682]: 
0     5
1     8
2    14
3    18
```